# QGIS 2.14 Renaming favourites

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to rename the favourites in QGis Browser ? My folder paths are pretty long and I'd like to see directly my folder name.

I'm sorry if it's already been answered, I've looked online but found nothing on this simple question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible in QGIS 2.14.x neither in 2.18.x. It would be a nice option though, I also have long paths. One workaround is to create shortcuts inside a shortest path folder. However, you cannot link the shortcut, you have to link the parent folder.